# How do I determine if a clearcase element has been moved/renamed?

Tags: clearcase

I have a given file on a given child stream. I want to compare the version on the stream to the same element on another stream. To do this, I need to figure out if the file has been moved on the child stream so I know what name to look for on the parent stream. However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to find rename events using the command line tools.

The only way I could find was to use cleartool diff on each version of the parent directory to look for the diff containing the rename, but it seems like there should be an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main options are summarized by [this thread](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=55226) and mention a search based on the OID o the file.

But I would first try a **[`cleartool lsvtree`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvtree.htm)**:

```
cleartool lsvtree -obs -branch theOtherBranch myFile
```

Try that from the "source" view (that is the one selecting the file with its current name in the current branch), and see if the `lsvtree` is able to display the version of that same file on the other branch.

The [OP bradtgmurray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1546/bradtgmurray)  reports:

- `lsvtree` lists element history with the current name for whatever stream, which isn't what is needed for detecting renamed file.
- the thread help suggesting the use of:

  - `cleartool desc -fmt '%On' <filename>@@` in the child and
  - `cleartool desc -fmt '%n' oid:<oid>` in the parent.

Comment: In cleartool lsvtree all elements were listed with the current name for whatever stream, unfortunately. Can you please edit your answer to include the information from that other thread with some minor corrections? I used `cleartool desc -fmt '%On' <filename>@@` in the child and `cleartool desc -fmt '%n' oid:<oid>` in the parent. The original thread states that %O and not %On is the oid fmt string.